# Deserialization via Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I try to deserialize the json to object and get error.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: A. Path '', line 0, position 0.
>      в Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
>      в Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
>      в Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
>      в Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
>      в Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      в Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      в Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)

```
json="{\"Email\":\"ui new user111715154920@email.com\",\"UserName\":\"ui new user111715154920\",\"PasswordQuestion\":\"Question ui new user111715154920\",\"IsAdmin\":false,\"Source\":0,\"MustResetPassword\":false,\"CellPhoneNo\":\"\",\"CellPhoneNo2\":\"\",\"CellPhoneNo3\":\"\",\"PagerNo\":\"\",\"PagerNo2\":\"\",\"NotifyBySMS\":false,\"NotifyByEmail\":false,\"NotifyByPopup\":false,\"NotifyByPush\":false,\"AllowPersonalDashboard\":false,\"AllowUnlimitedDashboardItems\":false,\"CanHaveUnlimitedAlerts\":false,\"StayLoggedIn\":false,\"IsActive\":false,\"AccountTypeID\":1,\"Groups\":{\"Items\":[{\"_id\":31,\"_name\":\"HCS Users\"}],\"NewItems\":[],\"RemovedItems\":[],\"TrackChanges\":false},\"CreatedBy\":0,\"CreatedOn\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"ModifiedBy\":0,\"ModifiedOn\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"ID\":85,\"Name\":\"ui new user111715154920\"}"
```

Classes:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class GERLinkListOfUserGroup
{
    private List<NameIDItem> newItems;
    private List<NameIDItem> removedItems;
    private bool trackChanges;
    private List<NameIDItem> items;

    [JsonProperty]
    public List<NameIDItem> NewItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == newItems)
            {
                newItems = new List<NameIDItem>();
            }

            return newItems;
        }
        set { newItems = value; }
    }
    [JsonProperty]
    public List<NameIDItem> RemovedItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == removedItems)
            {
                removedItems = new List<NameIDItem>();
            }

            return removedItems;
        }
        set { removedItems = value; }
    }
    [JsonProperty]
    public bool TrackChanges
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == trackChanges)
            {
                trackChanges = false;
            }
            return trackChanges;
        }
        set { trackChanges = value; }
    }
    [JsonProperty]
    public List<NameIDItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == items)
            {
                items = new List<NameIDItem>();
            }

            return items;
        }
        set { items = value; }
    }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class NameIDItem
{
    private string name;
    private int id;
    [JsonProperty]
    public string _name
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                name = "";
            }
            return name;
        }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    [JsonProperty]
    public int _id
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == id)
            {
                id = 0;
            }
            return id;
        }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public NameIDItem(){}

    public NameIDItem(string name, int id)
    {
        _name = name;
        _id = id;
    }
}


[JsonObject]
public class UserResponseJson
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Email2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Email3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool MustResetPassword { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string CellPhoneNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string CellPhoneNo2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string CellPhoneNo3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string PagerNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string PagerNo2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool NotifyBySMS { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool NotifyByEmail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool NotifyByPopup { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool NotifyByPush { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool AllowPersonalDashboard { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool AllowUnlimitedDashboardItems { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool CanHaveUnlimitedAlerts { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool StayLoggedIn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int AccountTypeID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public GERLinkListOfUserGroup Groups { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

> UserResponseJson responsedUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

Comment: Your json is not valid. Run it though here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: It's just complaining about the escape character.

Comment: It works without issue in simple console program. (.net 4.0 , newtonsof 6.0.8)

Comment: @iPogosov What version of Newtonsoft.Json are you using? I've deserialized your string to a dynamic object using the latest version; 7.0.1

Comment: Debug your code. I bet your passing an empty string into the DeserializeObject method.

Comment: I use the latest version of  Newtonsoft.Json. Downloaded it yesterday from nuget. Will try to modify the string.

Comment: @iPogosov I've removed my answer because I don't actually think it's what your problem is. If you were to copy / paste this code directly in to your app it should work, same goes for your original string. I replicated the issue you're having with error at line 0 position 0. It happens when you pass in invalid json such a string "foobar". It leads me to believe you're not actually passing the correct string in to DeserializeObject(). Can you show us the code where you are creating the string variable and actually passing it in to the method.Passing in an empty string will not result in an error

Comment: I found the problem. I updated the resharper few days ago and it's critical bug. The output window displays old output info. So the deserialization works fine. But I always got error and same output text.